# Removing require(_balances[user] >= amount) in solidity smart contract

Tags: solidity, web3js

if i remove the require(this) from a transfer function to save gas and leave it up to the error produced if the user doesn't have enough amount will it affect the function in any bad way ?

```
    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
        require(_balances[msg.sender] >= amount)
            _balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
            _balances[recipient] += amount;
            
            return true;
    }

    function transfer(address recipient, uint256 amount) external returns (bool) {
            _balances[msg.sender] -= amount;
            _balances[recipient] += amount;
            
            return true;
    }
```

Comment: Please provide your code in the question. Implementation of the token `transfer` function can be different in each contract so without the code we don't know how a specific change would affect users.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It depends on your solidity version and the datatype of `balances`.

I'm going to assume the `balances` is `mapping (address => uint256)`, because that's what most tokens use. As for the solidity versions, I'm going to split the answer.

#### Solidity <= 0.7.6

**DO NOT remove the check.** If you do, you open the function to integer underflow/overflow vulnerability.

Example:

- `_balances[msg.sender]` is 50
- `amount` is 100

So 50-100 usually results in -50. Since there are no negative numbers in `uint`, it wraps around zero, and continues the substraction from the maximum number available in the datatype. In case of `uint256`, the max number is `2^256 - 1` (approx. `10^77`).

Without the check, the `_balances[msg.sender] -= amount;` would underflow, resulting in the sender having not `-50` but `2^256 - 51` tokens. Which you don't want.

Read more about the vulnerability on https://swcregistry.io/docs/SWC-101

Edit: There's a well-known library called [SafeMath](https://docs.openzeppelin.com/contracts/3.x/api/math) (by OpenZeppelin), that also helps you to prevent underflow/overflow. Example use:

```
// reverts if underflow would happen
_balances[msg.sender] = _balances[msg.sender].sub(amount);
```

#### Solidity >= 0.8.0

It's safe to remove the check. Solidity 0.8+ performs the underflow/overflow check by default and the transaction reverts if underflow/overflow would occur.